# Windows Azure Hello World sample fails: Start role failed for one or more roles

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles

I can't run the Windows Azure Hello World sample. It gives me the following error:

"Start role failed for one or more roles".

I put the project in the root of my D drive to be sure that path length is not an issue. I also cleared the Azure temp folder.

I am using the newly released version 1.4 of the SDK.

Comment: Please check Windows eventlogs on your machine and see if there are any relevant errors that you spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common cause of this problem is that the development fabric (also known as "compute emulator") isn't running as Administrator on the local machine.  If you manually start the compute fabric, this may be the reason.  If you start the compute emulator from Visual Studio (e.g. by pressing F5), it will start the compute emulator running as administrator provided the VS instance is running as Administrator (you have to right click VS in the Start menu and select "Run As Administrator" to run it that way).

Another cause is that the web role is the startup project rather than the Azure service.  The Azure service (the one with the .cscfg under it) has to be the startup project (right click on it and select "Set as Startup Project").

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have an exception in the OnStart method of one of your Role(s).  I would:

1) Make sure that all exceptions are handled
2) Start logging the exceptions or put a breakpoint to see what's happening

Comment: That didn't help. It seems to be coming up with the error before the method is even called.